# Is it possible to calculate total standard deviation from daily rolling standard deviation values

Tags: python, pandas, math, standard-deviation

I have a DataFrame which contains a column that is the rolling standard deviation from day to day. (i.e. `df['daily_std'] = df['value'].rolling(2).std()`)

However, when I retrieve the DataFrame, it no longer contains the original values, `df['value']`, and they cannot be retrieved.

I need to get the single, total standard deviation for the entire series of original values (i.e. `df['total_std'] = df['value'].std()`. Is it possible, mathematically, to somehow calculate this total standard deviation from the individual rolling daily standard deviations, since the original values are no longer available?

Comment: Could you define "rolling standard deviation"?

Comment: It is just the standard deviation between each pair of numbers. I asked the same question on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site - what I am trying to do is not possible (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075692/282596)